# Rearrange list items by key value Python

Tags: python

This is my list.

```
 my_list1 = [
           {"id":"100", "question_set":"two"},{"qn_id":"101","question_set":"one"},{"qn_id":"102", "question_set":"three"}
    ]
```

questions_set_first_id_item, questions_set_second_id_item ,questions_set_third_id_item are obtained from database.

```
questions_set_first_id_item = "one"
questions_set_second_id_item = "two" 
questions_set_third_id_item = "three"
```

questions_set_first_id_item can be "one" or "two" or "three" and similarly with questions_set_second_id_item and questions_set_thrid_id_item but they cannot be same.

Now list needs to be rearranged questions_set_first_id_item then questions_set_second_id_item and questions_set_third_id_item's values
Output required:

```
my_list1 = [{"qn_id":"101","question_set":"one"},{"id":"100", "question_set":"two"},{"qn_id":"102", "question_set":"three"}
    ]
```

Another example

```
questions_set_first_id_item = "three"
questions_set_second_id_item = "two" 
questions_set_third_id_item = "one"
```

Now list needs to be rearranged questions_set_first_id_item then questions_set_second_id_item and questions_set_third_id_item's values
Output required:

```
my_list1 = [,{"qn_id":"102", "question_set":"three"}, ,{"id":"100", "question_set":"two"}, {"qn_id":"101","question_set":"one"}
        ]
```

How to rearrange index of list items according to users choice of question_set?

Comment: `my_list1[0], my_list1[2] = my_list1[2], my_list1[0]`? Why did you post `my_list2`? Also how does the user "wants" it to be rearranged?

Comment: @LeiYang What's the point of using strings as keys? `three` comes before `two`.

Comment: @Selcuk It should address 3! = 6 combinations . I have added at end of qn

Comment: @HimalAcharya Your expected output is completely different than your question text. If you want all permutations you need `list(itertools.permutations(my_list2, 3))`.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want. How is the desired order determined from the input? How do you know which lists aren't in order?

Comment: I dont need all combinations as output but should address user input combinations.
User input can be six possible combinations (3!) and I need only one output list according to user input combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to reorder according to a user-given list of question sets.
This can be solved with list / dict comprehensions:

```
expected_order = [questions_set_first_id_item, questions_set_second_id_item, questions_set_third_id_item]
items_by_question_set = {item["question_set"]: item for item in my_list1}
output_list = [items_by_question_set[qs] for qs in expected_order]
```

This code does not check whether indexes are valid. Look e.g. at the dictionary `.get` method for this.